# How to set the length of the RecyclerView to not exceed the screen

Tags: android, android-studio

I have RecyclerView, texts, buttons etc ... inside NestedScrollView.

When the recyclerview menu has a lot of items become high-altitude (match_parent) all elements such as buttons and text will be by the scrollbar to show elements , I want the height to be automatic but without the other elements disappearing.

How do I do this What do I add?

Comment: RecyclerView already scrolls. Remove the ScrollView parent.

Comment: I just want to have the length so fit that the rest of the elements appear

Comment: I want like that android:layout_height="wrap_content" Length must be by items , before other elements begin to disappear then enable scrollbar in recyclerview

Comment: Use a ConstraintLayout parent and set constraints.

Comment: example please ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your layout look something like this:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:width="match_parent"
        android:height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/top_elements_holder"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/recyclerview">

        <!-- Anything above the RecyclerView goes here -->

    </LinearLayout>

    <RecyclerView
        android:width="match_parent"
        android:height="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/top_elements_holder"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/bottom_elements_holder"
    />

    <LinearLayout
        android:width="match_parent"
        android:height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/bottom_elements_holder"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/recyclerview"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">

            <!-- Anything below the RecyclerView goes here -->

        </LinearLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

You'll obviously need to modify it to suit your needs.

With ConstraintLayout, you can set the RecyclerView's height to `match_constraint` (`0dp`), and set its top and bottom constraints. If you have elements above the RecyclerView, put them in the top LinearLayout, and the same for the bottom.

For more info on how ConstraintLayout works, you should read [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout).

Comment: I don't need NesteedScrollView?

Comment: I'll check and come back

Comment: finally , It's working but I have a question maybe the phone screen is small so some items will come out of the screen is there a solution ?

Comment: @user10797717 the RecyclerView scrolls.